# Backbone View bound to Collection not picking up add events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a view that has these functions -

```
  initialize:=>
    @populateSearchHistory()
    @el

  populateSearchHistory:=>
    console.log(pastSearches)
    @$el.find("#searchHistoryContainer").append(Handlebars.templates["$$ uri $$-searchHistory"]())
    @collection.add(stuff)


  @collection.on "add", (toAdd)->
    console.log(toAdd)
```

But "adding" is not logged. What is going on?

UPDATE-

I tried doing this in the initialize function -

```
initialize:=>
  @collection.on "add", @populateSearchHistory
```

where populateSearchHistory is now

```
populateSearchHistory:(toAdd)=>
  console.log(toAdd)
```

But, toAdd is an empty model, I need it to have the values as what I added.

UPDATE- compiled javascript

```
var _this = this;

({
  initialize: function() {
    _this.populateSearchHistory();
    return _this.el;
  },
  populateSearchHistory: function() {
    console.log(pastSearches);
    _this.$el.find("#searchHistoryContainer").append(Handlebars.templates["$$ uri $$-searchHistory"]());
    return _this.collection.add(stuff);
  }
});

this.collection.on("add", function(toAdd) {
  return console.log(toAdd);
});
```

UPDATE

OK - so the binding in the init function worked, and the uninitialized query being passed in was because I had a for loop going through the collection and adding each model in the collection - each model was undefined - why is this happening?

Comment: er..not really- it got screwed up when I copied and pasted - I'm pretty sure my real indentation is right because coffee is not yelling at me

Comment: I can post the compiled javascript

Comment: Why are you using => instead of -> this is already your view object so you don't need to use that (_this). You should also handle all your model/collection event listeners in the init method.

Answer (score 0):

here jsfiddle (updated) : http://jsfiddle.net/85YxD/

```
SearchModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

SearchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : SearchModel
});

myCollection = new SearchCollection();

SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function() {
       var _this = this;
        _this.populateSearchHistory();
   },

    populateSearchHistory: function() {
        var _this = this;
       // your code here
       var stuff = new SearchModel({
          key : 'value'          
       })

       //model can be added both way 
       console.log('model1 added.......');
       _this.options.list.add(stuff);

       //Or,  
       console.log('model2 added.......');
      _this.options.list.add({
          key1 : 'value1',
          key2 : 'value2'
       });

       //TODO : add loop for adding models here

       return _this;
   }

});

myCollection.on("add", function(toAdd) {
    console.log('added model', toAdd);
    console.log('updated collection', myCollection.toJSON());  
});


new SearchView({
   list : myCollection
});
```

​